# DBus .service file missing

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, dbus, ubuntu-11.10

I am building custom `dbus` service for my own demands and want it to start automatically when someone need it. For that purpose I've created `.service` file like this

```
[D-Bus Service]
Name=com.mycompany.servicename
Exec=/home/myuser/Workspace/service-start
User=myuser
```

Here I just changed the actual name of service and executable but this is not the point. I've double checked real names - it matches exactly.
I've placed this file under name com.mycompany.servicename.service to /usr/share/dbus-1/services folder (I am using Ubuntu 11.10)
Executable file has `x` permissions for everyone.
And here is the problem - when I am trying to start client that performs

```
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
bus.get_object('com.mycompany.servicename','/path/to/object')
```

I get `dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.mycompany.servicename was not provided by any .service files`

Object with path `'/path/to/object'` is registered right after service start.
I just don't get why `dbus` can't find my `.service` file. Maybe I am missing something? Any ideas?

**Edit**
I've managed to get D-BUS automatically start my script. The section of `.service` file should be named `[D-BUS Service]` instead of `[D-Bus service]`

Comment: Where are you putting your .service file? The man page for dbus-daemon refers to the XDG Base Dir Spec, and that intern seems to suggest you should put it in ~/.local/share (see http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no evidence of other `.service` files that provide `session buses` but at the same time there are a lot of them in the folder I mentioned earlier (/usr/share/dbus-1/services). The name of the folder I got [here](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/D-Bus/Autostart_Services)

Comment: @pss, you should create a answer and accept it by yourself!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a short summary of the comments...

Create the subdirectory `dbus-1/services/` in one of the directories named in the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html).  Usually, `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/` works just fine.  Enter the new subdirectory, create a file called `com.mycompany.servicename.service` and add the lines:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=com.mycompany.servicename
Exec=/home/myuser/Workspace/service-start
User=myuser
```

Please note that **D-BUS** in `[D-BUS Service]` needs to be capitalized.

That's it!

Comment: does this mean that the dbus-daemon would want to manage my service? (I expect myself to start my application *manually* that would register itself on dbus for a particular message interface and object path via dbus-python. But I get the `ServiceUnknown` exception.)